# Are links vunerable to csrf?

Tags: security, csrf

I'm looking CSRF for my e-commerce site. I've implemented a token based approach for forms.

I have a **checkout** link on the basket page of my site that simply links to the address page. Once on the address page various checks are done to make sure the user is logged in and has items in their basket. It then pulls out the users existing addresses based on their user_id which is stored in the session.

My question is, is there any vulnerability in the **checkout** link? It's not altering any data in any way.

Comment: it all comes down to your code. there's no way to answer this properly without more details. You could have something (stupid) like `if (isset($_REQUEST['dothis'])) { eval($_REQUEST['dothis']); }`. even if that `dothis` is a hidden/unpublished parameter, it's still a hideous vulnerability.

Comment: Well, what exactly happens if that checkout page is getting requested? Is there some automation on that page that doesn’t require the user’s action but still causes a server-side effect?

Comment: I think I was perhaps struggling to understand the concept of csrf. I now understand and I can see that there isn't a csrf vulnerability where I thought there might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only retrieve data from the request, then it is safe from CSRF.

CSRF is an attack which tricks a user into making a request that changes something (posting a comment (possibly spam!), buying something, voting for something, changing their account details, etc).

Comment: [CSRF](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html) is not just limited to requests with side effects, however, such requests are rather valuable.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is not a "vulnerable" or "not vulnerable" type of vulnerability. More of a "can something be exploited?". Let me elaborate.

The entire idea behind CSRF is to force the user (through any means available) to perform a change as themselves programmatically (and preferably without their consent). The way to do this is to find a part of the site you are trying to attack which has a **significant** request which is either:

- Entirely done using `GET` parameters (at which point you can use an `img` tag to trick the user's browser into triggering it)
- Does not have a unique CSRF token in the request, but in this case, you will need either of the following:

  - A page on the site with an XSS vulnerability in order to leverage AJAX to do the request
  - A misconfiguration of their server, causing them to blanket-sent CORS headers. This is rare.

CSRF, by itself, is rare (most websites use `POST` for a lot of things. It is very rare to have to resort to image tags). The more likely combination is CSRF+XSS, though variants can be found.

The key to defending against CSRF is not "omg my link may be hacked!!!". Moreso, make sure that your requests which can be replayed using `GET` are idempotent (i.e. do not cause a change of state), and that anything else uses a one-time token to prevent automated replays.

Comment: [Idempotence](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.1.2) does not mean that it’s free of side-effects: “Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request.”

Comment: Great, thanks this help me understand the concept better

Comment: @Gumbo: Correct. I'll re-phrase.